# Getting NullpointerException in Mockito

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mockito

I have actual method below:

```
public ResponseEntity<Message> catEnter(@PathVariable("catId") BigInteger catId, @RequestBody Catrequest catReq, HttpServletRequest request) throws CatDataException, InvalidCatExcecatption {
    Message message = new Message();
    try {
        message = catManager.submitData(catReq.getMessage(), catId, request);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CatDataAppException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return (ResponseEntity<Message>) restResponse(message, request.getMethod());
    // Getting null pointer exception in above line
}
```

I am using mockito for my test code as below:

```
@Test
public void submitData() throws Exception {
    Message mes = new Message();
    mes.setCode("00");
    mes.setMessage("hi");
    ResponseEntity<Message> responseentity = ((ResponseEntity<Message>) catController.catEnter(BigInteger.valueOf(3431), catRequest, mockRequest));
}
```

I'm getting null pointer exception, Message going as a null, even I set the value explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

You pass `mockRequest` when making that call to your production code:

```
ResponseEntity<Message> responseentity = ... catController.catEnter(... mockRequest));
```

And your production call does:

```
return (ResponseEntity<Message>) restResponse(message, request.getMethod());
```

So the only conclussion: `mockRequest` is null!

So, first make sure that the passed variable is *not* null; like:

```
Request mockedRequest = mock(Request.class);
```

Or, use the @Mock annotation in case that `mockedRequest` is a field in your test class.

On top of that; you probably want to do some mock-specification, like:

```
when(mockedRequest.getMethod()).thenReturn( whatever )
```

But beyond that, you are lacking a lot of the fundamental basics of Java:

- naming conventions: variable names go camelCase, like `entityResponse`. And typically, tests are named like `testCatEnter` to express the method that is tested.
- You have casts ... where they are not required.
- You have quite some code there ... that is unused, like the `mes` declaration in your test method.

Long story short: I have the feeling that you are **overburdening** yourself dramatically. First learn the basics; then go for the advanced Mockito stuff.

Comment: I have checked mockRequest is not null, I am getting message object is null even explicitly assign the values. I have tried @Mock annotation and Message message= mock(Message.class); but no use still getting same null pointer exception

Comment: Then I think you should step back and create a **full** [mcve] for us. The code you are showing right now is not "complete" enough to really understand what is going on.

Comment: below is the mock line
when((String)restHttpClient.getForCat(any(RequestCat.class), any(RequestEye.class))).thenReturn(catData);
below is the actual line
cat= (String) restServiceHelper.getForCat(RequestCat, RequestEye);  
In above line am getting null